# "Add SAML" is disabled on AD FS 2.0 manager

Tags: adfs2.0

When I add Relying Party manually on AD FS Manager I am able to update "Endpoints" and set SAML Logout, but when I add RP supplying the URL to federatedmetadata.xml file and after the RP is created the AD FS manager doesn't allow me to add SAML logout link to my newly created RP.

I guess if I have to configure my RP using only URL to the XML then the only way to add SAML logout is to include it in the federatedmetadata.xml, but I don't know how to configure the XML that would contain single sign out link and what worries me the most is that I won't be able to do it because if I change my XML manually it will become unusable since the AD FS Manager starts throwing exceptions once you change the XML.

How can I add SAML Logout on the AD FS 2.0 for my RP when the AD FS Manager completely disables such an option?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to allow managing endpoints while having RP set up on AD FS with URL pointing to FederationMetadata.xml I had to create my own FederationMetadata.xml with all the necessary endpoints, signatures, encryption, etc. Before that I used FedAuthUtil and it didn't do all the job.

Thanks a lot to Evan Larsen's [blog post](http://evanlarsen.blogspot.pt/2011/06/generate-federation-metadata-xml-file.html) who did pretty much all the dirty work, even though some changes had to be applied.

```
public class FederationMetadataHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    private object criticalSection = new object();
    private volatile EntityDescriptor entity;
    private string relyingPartyUrl = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings[""];
    private string relyingPartySignOutUrl = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings[""];
    private string signingCertificateThumbprint = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings[""];
    private string encryptionCertificateThumbprint = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings[""];

    public FederationMetadataHandler() { }

    // This tells the website that this service is re-usable
    // so it does not need to run the code everytime. It will keep an instances of this
    // class and just return the FederationMetadata.xml file once its been processed once
    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        EnsureInitialized();
        context.Response.Clear();
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
        context.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

        MetadataSerializer serializer = new MetadataSerializer();
        serializer.WriteMetadata(context.Response.OutputStream, entity);
    }

    private void EnsureInitialized()
    {
        if (entity == null)
        {
            lock (criticalSection)
            {
                if (entity == null)
                {
                    HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
                    Uri baseUri = new Uri(new Uri(context.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri), context.Request.ApplicationPath);

                    ApplicationServiceDescriptor sts = new ApplicationServiceDescriptor();

                    SingleSignOnDescriptor sso = new SingleSignOnDescriptor();

                    ServiceProviderSingleSignOnDescriptor spsso = new ServiceProviderSingleSignOnDescriptor();

                    FillRequestedClaimTypes(sts.ClaimTypesRequested);
                    FillEndPoints(sts);
                    FillSupportedProtocols(sts);
                    FillSigningKey(sts);
                    FillEncryptionKey(sts);
                    FillSingleSignOutEndPoints(spsso);

                    EntityId id = new EntityId(this.relyingPartyUrl);
                    entity = new EntityDescriptor(id);
                    entity.SigningCredentials = GetSigningCredentials();

                    entity.RoleDescriptors.Add(sts);
                    entity.RoleDescriptors.Add(spsso);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void FillRequestedClaimTypes(ICollection<DisplayClaim> claimTypes)
    {
        // possibly make this read from a config file in the future..
        //ClaimsProvider.GetDisplayClaims().ForEach(dc => claimTypes.Add(dc));

        DisplayClaim name = new DisplayClaim(ClaimTypes.Name);
        claimTypes.Add(name);
    }

    private void FillEndPoints(ApplicationServiceDescriptor sts)
    {
        EndpointAddress activeEndpoint = new EndpointAddress(this.relyingPartyUrl);
        sts.TargetScopes.Add(activeEndpoint);
        sts.PassiveRequestorEndpoints.Add(activeEndpoint);
    }

    private void FillSupportedProtocols(ApplicationServiceDescriptor sts)
    {
        sts.ProtocolsSupported.Add(new Uri(WSFederationConstants.Namespace));
    }

    private void FillSigningKey(ApplicationServiceDescriptor sts)
    {
        KeyDescriptor key = GetKeyDescriptor(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine, X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, signingCertificateThumbprint, KeyType.Signing);
        sts.Keys.Add(key);
    }

    private void FillEncryptionKey(ApplicationServiceDescriptor sts)
    {
        KeyDescriptor key = GetKeyDescriptor(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine, X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, encryptionCertificateThumbprint, KeyType.Encryption);
        sts.Keys.Add(key);
    }

    private void FillSingleSignOutEndPoints(ServiceProviderSingleSignOnDescriptor spsso)
    {
        spsso.ProtocolsSupported.Add(new Uri("urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:protocol"));
        spsso.ProtocolsSupported.Add(new Uri("urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"));
        spsso.AssertionConsumerService.Add(0, new IndexedProtocolEndpoint(0, new Uri("urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"), new Uri(relyingPartyUrl)));
        spsso.SingleLogoutServices.Add(new ProtocolEndpoint(new Uri("urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect"), new Uri(relyingPartySignOutUrl)));
    }

    private Microsoft.IdentityModel.SecurityTokenService.X509SigningCredentials GetSigningCredentials()
    {
        X509Certificate2 certificate = GetCertificate(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine, X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, encryptionCertificateThumbprint);
        if (certificate == null) throw new Exception("Signing certificate is not found");
        return new Microsoft.IdentityModel.SecurityTokenService.X509SigningCredentials(certificate);
    }

    private KeyDescriptor GetKeyDescriptor(StoreName storeName, StoreLocation storeLocation, X509FindType findByType, object findByValue, KeyType keyType)
    {
        X509Certificate2 certificate = GetCertificate(storeName, storeLocation, findByType, findByValue);
        if (certificate == null) throw new Exception(string.Format(@"Certificate for type \""{0}\"" is not found", findByType));
        X509RawDataKeyIdentifierClause clause = new X509SecurityToken(certificate).CreateKeyIdentifierClause<X509RawDataKeyIdentifierClause>();
        KeyDescriptor key = new KeyDescriptor(new SecurityKeyIdentifier(clause));
        key.Use = keyType;
        return key;
    }

    private X509Certificate2 GetCertificate(StoreName storeName, StoreLocation storeLocation, X509FindType findBy, object findValue)
    {
        X509Certificate2 certificate = null;
        X509Store store = new X509Store(storeName, storeLocation);
        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);
        X509Certificate2Collection matchedCertificates = store.Certificates.Find(findBy, findValue, false);
        if (matchedCertificates.Count > 0) certificate = matchedCertificates[0];
        return certificate;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you added the RP trust manually, did you tick the box for "Enable support for SAML" as well as "Enable support for "WS-Fed"?

When you do that both "Add" boxes are enabled.

Comment: The thing is that when I create RP manually or import federatedmetadata.xml from local folder everything is fine, I can change endpoints, but I can't do so when federatedmetadata.xml is pointing to a URL.

Comment: Changing the xml is not undoable. Take a look at the ADFS metadata as an example. Look for the SingleLogoutService element. And you need to remove the signature (if it was signed), because editing the xml will invalidate the signature.

Comment: @paullem, I removed the signing, but looking at the STS xml I cannot figure out where to put the <SingleLogoutService /> node in my RP xml. When I do "Update from federated metadata" on AD FS it doesn't reflect my logout enpoint. Do you happen to know where I have to put this node in RP xml: `<SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location="https://rp.com/Logout.aspx"/>`

Comment: As I said. Look at the ADFS metadata. There is a sample of an SPSSODescriptor and it contains a SingleLogoutService element. If you do that for your RP (SP in classic SAML speak) then it should be OK.